# Tables in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want group based security in my application. However I don't understand how to use it.

Looking at the two different database schemas from the appendix, I got some questions. Am I supposed to extend the group_members table with password, enabled, first name etc? Or am I supposed to have another table named for instance `user` which hold this info? If I need, why do I need the group_member table?

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html

Answer (score -1):

It is not compulsory to use group table. you can also use single or two table for authentication. Refer the following link for reference.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/